# Excel - Different Trendlines for Same Data... What?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two columns of data, each 273 rows long. They are charted as a Scatter Plot.

In my first iteration, I charted Data_A as the X-axis, and Data_B as the Y-axis. It generated a trendline with the formula: y=-0.0026x + 3.9124, with an R^2 of 0.8312.

After reviewing my data, I remembered the Y-axis should always be the "dependent" variable, and the X-axis "independent". Under this framework, my data was backwards and needed to be flipped.

I simply clicked the scatterplot data, and manually drag/dropped the columns around. Now Data_A was the Y-axis and Data_B was the X-axis. Easy.

**HOWEVER**: My trendline formula has now changed to y=-317.11x + 1383.7 with an R^2 of 0.8312. Huh? Basic algebra can quickly prove the inverse of the original trendline should be y=-384.6x + 1504.8.

Accordingly, the trendline doesn't hit the same intercept point. In the first chart, the trendline intercepts around 1505. In the second chart, the trendline intercepts at 1384.

Is this some kind of glitch with Excel? How is this even possible? I am racking my brain trying to solve this puzzle.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think what you are seeing is correct. My (perhaps faulty) memory of statistics is the regression line is a computation such that you are minimizing the y distance from the points to the line. When you invert the columns you are changing what you are minimizing. I'm not sure why the R^2 value did not change.

Comment: Thanks. The resulting equation just looks and feels totally wrong. It misses a chunk of data points the original equation intersects nicely. Damn you statistics! :p

Comment: depending on your data that r^2 is really nice. You could always rescale your plot so that it passes the eye test.... like this ;-)